# WiFi direct on 5Ghz band?

Tags: wifi-direct

Can an Android device with a 5Ghz-capable Wi-Fi chip, such as the Nexus 5, use Wi-Fi direct on the 5Ghz band?

If so, how? Couldn't find anything of substance on the net.

Comment: Only did a quick research, but seems Wi-Fi direct is not supported on 5GHz. While probably unrelated, from [Sony Bravia Smart TV manual](http://docs.esupport.sony.com/imanual/NA/EN/hx750/wfdirect_wfintegrated.html): "*Wi-Fi Direct compatible devices: 2.4GHz connection (5GHz not supported).*" Otherwise, it *might* be possible by forcing the configuration of Wi-Fi direct to use 5GHz *[on Linux](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.wireless.general/110171)*, but I can't promise anything on Android.

Comment: [Post 45](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2033231&page=5) May help you

Comment: @beeshyams That seems to relate only to certain channels.

Answer (score 2):

You might or might not be able to depending on your device. I tested this on OnePlus 5 with Android 8.1 and 5GHz P2P GO works (channel = 48, i.e. freq = 5.240GHz). Only a few 5GHz channels however actually works though.

Basically you need to use a hidden ([light greylist](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/runtime/+/94fec32/appcompat/hiddenapi-light-greylist.txt#4416) at the time of this post) API `Landroid/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager;->setWifiP2pChannels(Landroid/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager$Channel;IILandroid/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager$ActionListener;)V`. See [here](https://github.com/Mygod/VPNHotspot/blob/15d838893c1c6e92bb33efcb69b7d9840ed92f72/mobile/src/main/java/be/mygod/vpnhotspot/RepeaterService.kt#L147) for example usage. You can also try out [my app](https://github.com/Mygod/VPNHotspot) to test whether your phone supports it if you have root.

You might also need to remove an entry named `p2p_no_go_freq` in your `p2p_supplicant_overlay.conf` if there is one. It's located in `/system/etc/wifi` or `/vendor/etc/wifi` depending on your Android system version.